# Дописать условие если в строке нет цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, множества

Входные данные
На вход программе подаётся символьная строка.
Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести в одной строке все различные цифры, которые встречаются в исходной строке, в порядке возрастания. Если в строке нет цифр, нужно вывести слово 'NO' - не могу добавить это условие.

```
text = set(input())
n_list = []
for i in text:
    if '0' <= i <= '9':
        n_list.append(i)
print(''.join(sorted(n_list)))
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, заголовок вопроса в соответствие с его содержимым.

Comment: Так ваш код вроде работает, или вы условие дописать не можете?

Comment: Условие дописать не получалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементарно, если знать небольшие хитрости питона:

```
print(''.join(sorted(n_list)) or 'NO')
```

В случае, если получится не пустая строка, то, что справа от `or` не будет использовано. А вот если получится пустая строка - тогда результатом `or` будет то, что справа от него.

Comment: CrazyElf, точно))) Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
print(''.join(sorted(n_list))) if n_list else 'NO')
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо огромное!